# Simplifying this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to write the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^N nx^n$$

in a form that does not involve the summation notation, for example $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I've attempted multiple ways including using generating functions however no luck

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Does it look like the derivative of something you could sum?

Comment: From wolframalpha, this seems to be your target expression: $ ((N x - N - 1) x^{N + 1} + x)/(1 - x)^2$.

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30741/

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

First of all, we have that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}x^n=\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}$$
for $x\neq1$. So 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{N}nx^n&=x\sum_{n=0}^{N}nx^{n-1}\\
&=x\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{d}{dx}x^{n}\\
&=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{N}x^{n}\\
&=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\\
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: (+1) But your mind was 4 seconds faster than mine. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^Nnx^n&=x\sum_{n=0}^Nnx^{n-1}\\&=x\left(\sum_{n=0}^Nx^n\right)'\\&=x\left(\frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}\right)'.\end{align}

Comment: Great minds think alike :)  +1