# Evaluating a finite sum.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, summation, alternative-proof

Amid one exercise I was solving, I came across the following finite sum:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N} n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n.$$

This sum was evaluated in one of my classes, but I don't understand/agree with the resolution provided. For context, I present the resolution presented in class:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^N n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n = \sum_{n=0}^N n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n = \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=0}^N n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1} \color{red}{= \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=0}^N \left( \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^n \right)'} = \frac{3}{2} \left( \sum_{n=0}^N \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \right) ' = \frac{3}{2} \left( \frac{1.5^{N+1} - 1}{1.5-1} \right)'.$$

In the step I colored in red, it seems like we took the derivative of $(1.5)^n$ with respect to $1.5$, which I don't know if is possible. In the case that such computation makes sense, then everything that follows is clear, but I don't think derivatives with respect to a constant make sense.

Thus, I am looking for an alternative way of evaluating this sum.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3145414/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119636/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180198/42969

Comment: That's a terrible way to write a sensible operation.  I think the intent becomes clear if you replace $\frac 32$ with $x$ and differentiate with respect to $x$.  You can then evaluate at $x=\frac 32$.

Comment: You can't derivate with respect to a number. One derivates with respect to variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$\sum_{n=0}^N  x^n $$
derive with respect to $x$ and then plug $x=3/2$.

Comment: "Derive"...or better: integrate?

Comment: “Consider and derive” $\sum nx^n$… or better $\sum x^n$?

Comment: @DonAntonio is it ok now?

Comment: @SineoftheTime Indeed it is...though no need to say what to plug: the OP could do this by himself.